# C++ Library Dynamically Linked to a Java Library

Tags: java, c++, dynamic-linking, object-files

I'm writing a C++ plugin for an application.  The plugin is a .o file.   Call this code/functionality as being "C".

I also wrote a Java library.  Think of the code and functionality as being "J".

Next I used JNI's Invocation API to allow C to call J.  Now C can create objects, call methods, pass / receive values from Java objects or static methods.  Conceptually:

```
 C
JNI       method call -------->   J
 C        <----------- Result R
return R
```

Plugin C calls J via JNI.  A useful value R is computed in J, returned to C, and eventually returned to the application.

I individually tested codes J, C, and JNI with "stub mains", and each piece works on its own.  R is correct.  The problem is when the plugin tries to create a VM using calls to JNI:

```
./myPlugin.so: undefined symbol: JNI_CreateJavaVM
```

I believe the problem is that my C++ .o file wants to dynamically link to libjvm.so, but either doesn't know how to, or something is preventing ld.so from linking at runtime.

When I ran JNI as its own code with a stub main (that is, I did essentially the same thing, but as an application with a main function rather than a .o file) the same thing happened, but it was clearly a matter of ld.so not being able to find libjvm.so.   Defining:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_73/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

allowed ld.so to do its job correctly.  However, defining LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the Java libs isn't working for my JNI code in the .o file.

Are the rules of dynamic linking different for object file libraries?
Should I try to statically link libjvm.so into my .o file?  How would one even go about doing that?

I'm on completely uncharted territory for me, and feeling a bit lost.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you did -ljni during linking?

Comment: Don't try to call Java from non-Java main-program.
(JNI is meant for the opposite: calling native code from Java main-program.)

Comment: Not true.  The Invocation API (part of JNI) does just that.  I got it working.  The issue was that I had two versions of Java installed on that system.  One was being used for compiling the C++ code, and the other was being used to invoke the Java program.  The versions were clashing.